# Stream вместо foreach

Tags: java, java-stream

Пытаюсь реализовать добавление объектов, получаемых из storage по id в список не через цикл, а с помощью stream, пока не очень получается.

```
Storage storage;
Set<Long> resultIds = new HashSet<>();
Set<Object> result = new HashSet<>();
 
for (var id : resultIds) {
    result.add(storage.getObject(id).get());
}
//так не работает
result.stream().collect(object -> storage.getObject(id -> resultIds.forEach()).get());
```

Вроде бы просто все - добавляем в список result все объекты, полученные по id из списка resultIds из storage, а в stream не работает...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Буквальный перевод:

```
result = resultIds.stream()
    .map(id -> storage.getObject(id).get())
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

- `.stream()` нужно вызывать не от результата, а от исходных данных, которые обрабатываем (у вас это набор id-шников).
- В `map` пишем лямбду, которая по `id` получает нужный объект - по сути это просто внутренняя часть из строки `result.add(storage.getObject(id).get());`.

  Аргументом метода `.map()` должна быть функция, которая преобразовывает элемент исходной последовательности в элемент новой последовательности.
- Дальше все элементы собираем (`.collect()`) в нужную структуру данных - у вас это `Set`, значит используем коллектор `Collectors.toSet()`.

Comment: Супер, спасибо, объяснили в двух словах!